# C++ const array change without reason

Tags: c++

I have a problem with a piece of code. I'll provide you a simplified version :

```
class AdvancedImage
{
    Image *_source;
    int _w;
    int _h;

    AdvancedImage(const Image *src, const PointFloat corners[], int w, int h)
    {
        InitializeInstanceFields();
        _source = new Image(src->data, src->h, src->w);
        _w = w;
        _h = h;

        PointFloat newPoints[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            newPoints[i] = corners[i];
        }

        /* Initialisation continue... */
    }

    InitializeInstanceFields()
    {
        _w = 0;
        _h = 0;
    }
}

class Image
{
    unsigned char *data;
    int width;
    int height;
    int size;

    Image(const unsigned char newData[], int h, int w)
    {
        InitializeInstanceFields();
        this->height = h;
        this->width = w;
        this->size = h * w;
        this->data = new unsigned char[this->size];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        {
            this->data[i] = newData[i];
        }
    }
}

class PointFloat
{
    float X;
    float Y;

    PointFloat(float x, float y)
    {
        this->X = x;
        this->Y = y;
    }
}
```

And I'm using the `AdvancedImage` like this :

```
void myFunction (const Image *img, const PointFloat corners[])
{
    AdvancedImage *advImg = 0;
    /* Some code */
    advImg = new AdvancedImage(img, corners, 15, 30);
    /* Code continue */
}
```

My problem is that the values in `corners` change after doing the `new AdvancedImage`. I try to debug, and I saw something I can't explain. In constructor `AdvancedImage`, corners[0] is {76.0, 45.0}. I added a watch to `&corners`, in constructor `new Image` values don't change, but when code return from constructor (goes to line `_w = w;`) values are now something like {7.7877970e40, 0.2554460e-20}.

I've looked for a solution but nothing do. How can I solve this problem ? Where can it come from ?

Comment: `*Image _source;`? There are several syntax errors in your code. Please make sure it all compiles and shows the intended issue before posting. See [mcve].

Comment: Side note: your example code leaks memory. AdvancedImage._source is never deallocated.

Comment: @Darhuuk I have a ~AdvancedImage with a delete for _source but I didn't provide all the code here.

Comment: how is a `PointFloat` defined

Comment: Not sure if this is the case but I had similar problems when passing arrays to constructors, somehow data was lost. The data is lost when it goes out of scope. So b[0] = a[0], so a[0] and b [0] point to same data, try std::cout << &a[0] and same with b, in my case it gave me the same address. I solved it by using memcpy to actually copy data from one array to other. Search for memcpy or std::copy, since memcpy is an old C method.

Comment: @sp2danny PointFloat is a class with an X and an Y, both are float.

Comment: Use `std::vector<unsigned  char>` instead of `new` and `unsigned char*`.

Comment: we probably cant solve this without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but a guess is that the `Image` constructor is buggy and writes in memory it shouldn't.

Comment: Side note: you should read about rule of five and even better about rule of Zero.